# How to remove an item of array and update order index of array in mongodb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Now I have a "answers" array and I want to remove the first of this array but index item of this array is 1 but not 0. I don't know mongodb has support remove item array and update index array ?
My code:

Before remove:

> array (
>   '_id' => new MongoId("52818f9ad069feed198b4567"),
>   'answers' => array (
>
> ```
> '0' => 
>        array (
>               'by' => new MongoId("52818ec2d069fe90058b4567"),
>               'content' => '<p>Ok, testing<br /> &nbsp;</p> ',
>               'date' => new MongoInt32(1384222656),
>              ),
> '1' => 
>              array (
>                'by' => new MongoId("528192acd21b6310188b4567"),
>                'content' => 'test',
>                'date' => new MongoInt32(1384224360),
>               ),
> ```
>
> ),

After remove the first item of answers array

> array (
>   '_id' => new MongoId("52818f9ad069feed198b4567"),
>   'answers' => array (
>
> ```
> '1' => 
>              array (
>                'by' => new MongoId("528192acd21b6310188b4567"),
>                'content' => 'test',
>                'date' => new MongoInt32(1384224360),
>               ),
> ```
>
> ),

My result needs

> array (
>   '_id' => new MongoId("52818f9ad069feed198b4567"),
>   'answers' => array (
>
> ```
> '0' => 
>              array (
>                'by' => new MongoId("528192acd21b6310188b4567"),
>                'content' => 'test',
>                'date' => new MongoInt32(1384224360),
>               ),
> ```
>
> ),

My English very bad but please help me !

Comment: What code are you using to remove the first entry? As `0` is normally the first array key, you actually want to remove the second?

Comment: Above code is an example data that I store in mongodb. I want:
1. Remove the first entry
2. Update index of the second entry to 0.
Have function in mongodb can do that ?

Comment: Array_values will reset keys

Answer (score 0):

use `$db.collection.update( {array('_id' => new MongoId("52818f9ad069feed198b4567")),
                    array( $unset=> array(
                                '0'=> true
                              )
                    )
                  )`
use `$db.collection.update( {array(),
                    array( $unset=> array(
                                '0'=> true
                              )
                    )
                  )`

to make the same modification for every documents.